# Rest API restore last connection

Tags: c#, rest, http

I am working on a Rest API. So far I build a Webview where the user can make inputs and send them to the server. When the server receives the information it will start a program and do some calculations. The problem here is that opening the program needs a lot of time. So the user has to wait for +20 seconds. 
The point is that the user will change data of the same object and send them back to the server. When the server gets these data again it has to open the program again so that the user has to wait for another 20 seconds.

The program is referenced as a library. I create an instance of it within the controller class. So each time the server gets a new request it will open an instance, pass the data to the program and return the result to the client.

My question here is: Is there a way to avoid opening an instance for each request and instead open an instance temporarily for each user?

**Edit:**
The program is written in VBA. It is a configurator which calculates whether an option works out or not. I will access it by creating an instance of it:
`Configurator conf = new Configurator`
After that you can either create a new position or recall an old one by passing an ID like this:
`conf.ID = id;`
This process needs a lot of time because the program is collecting a lot of data from a database.
So this is the process I want to skip and instead use the object I created before. 
After that you can pass other data to the program/object like height etc.

Comment: We don't even know what "*the program*" is so we can't know how to use it. Could you add some detail?

Comment: Ok thanks for the suggestion. I just edited my post. I hope it is now easier to understand.

Comment: "The program is written in VBA"  Well there's yer problem. Rewrite that stuff in .net and your options will expand greatly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency injection engines like Autofac. Register your program instance onApplicationStart as a singleton instance. Then whenever you want an instance of the program.dll, autofac will give you the same instance according to your defined registration config which is singleton.